# How to draw arrows with the same length as the one of the axes?

Tags: gnuplot

I would like to draw arrows for the axes such that they should be started from the origin and ended at the maximum values of the variables. Could I perform it somehow?

Answer (score 3):

The `graph` coordinate system refers to the actual plotting area, where 0 is the left/bottom border and 1 is the right/top border.

For example the following command would place an arrow spanning the entire width of the plot (i.e., being as long as the *x* axis) at the level of 2.3 on the (first) *y* axis:

```
set arrow from graph 0, first 2.3 to graph 1, first 2.3
```